# UK Transit Visa - confusion on whether I need it

Tags: visas, uk, transit, ireland, macedonian-citizens

I am traveling to Montenegro from Dublin and I need to transit through London. 
I have a biometric Macedonian passport and an Irish visa.

Do I need a visa to transit through London? I'm not sure if I qualify for 'Irish biometric visa'

Comment: What type of Irish visa do you have? Did you provide your biometric information as part of your visa application?

Comment: @Traveller Conference/Event visa. The biometric information is inside my passport...

Answer (score 1):

An Irish biometric visa is marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section. If you have that then you do not need a visa to transit.

If you don't have that you will need a visa.

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/macedonia/transit/somewhere_else/no

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/macedonia/transit/somewhere_else/yes

Comment: a uniform format category D visa for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland

Do you know what this part means? Because we're not required any visas for entry into EEA/Switzerland countries

Comment: @Hydroxis: What do you have an Irish visa for, then? Ireland is in the EEA.

Comment: @Hydroxis That's talking about a specific form of long-term visa See e.g. here for a description https://ukimmigrationspecialist.com/2012/07/28/what-is-a-valid-uniform-format-category-d-visa-for-entry-to-a-state-in-the-european-economic-area-eea/

Comment: @Hydroxis does your visa have ‘BIVS’ endorsed on it?

Comment: @SamJones I don't have my passport here but:

https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassychina/visas/BIVS-information-note-EN.pdf

3 B says that C visas for Conference/Event are endorsed with BIVS.

EDIT: this is for chinese and indian citizens only..

Comment: Then you are fine to transit if it has it, make sure in your passport @Hydroxis